# submit работает со второго раза

Tags: jquery

Мне нужно, чтобы этот код срабатывал с первого нажатия на сабмит.

```
jQuery(function() {
    var x = false;
    jQuery(document).on('submit','#bit_exchange_form',function(){   
        if(x){
            return true;
        }
        var form = jQuery(this);
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/requests/bit_exchange_step_2.php",
            data: jQuery("#bit_exchange_form").serialize(),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                if(data.status == "success") {
                    x = true;
                    jQuery('#loading_image').show(); // show animation
                    form.submit();
                } else {
                    jQuery("#bit_exchange_results").html(data.msg);
                }
            }
        });
        return x;
    });
});
```

Таким образом остановил бесконечный цикл сабмит, но теперь форма работает только со второго клика.

Comment: К сожалению не помог...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jQuery.ajax` асинхронная команда, поэтому `return x;` не будет дожидаться выполнение ajax и сразу вернет значение.
Как решение можно забиндить кнопку submit, это решит проблему с бесконечным циклом

```js
jQuery(function() {
     jQuery('#bit_exchange_button').on('click', function(e){
      var $form = $('#bit_exchange_form');
         jQuery.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "response_ajax.php",
             data: $form.serialize(),
             dataType: "json",
             success: function (data) {
                 if(data.status == "success") {
                     $form.submit();
                 } else {
                     jQuery("#bit_exchange_results").html(data.msg);
                 }
             }
         });
     });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="bit_exchange_form" action="#">
  <input type="text" name="msg">
  <button id="bit_exchange_button" type="button">Сохранить</button>
 </form>
<div id="bit_exchange_results"></div>
```

Comment: Просто не знаю как поблагодарить Вам.
Было так <input type="submit" class="submitBtn" id="submit" value="Отправить" /> заменил на <button id="bit_exchange_button" type="button">Сохранить</button> и скирпт ваш заработал!!!